# LINQ order by local list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have list 'companies' from database.

And then I have another dictionary like:

```
Dictionary<int, string> ordering = new Dictionary<int, string>();
ordering.Add(1, "VIP");
ordering.Add(2, "VIP+");
ordering.Add(3, "Regular");
```

The companies list has to be ordered by this Dictionary.

How can I do that?

I can't join 'companies' with dictionary 'ordering', if I do I get an exception.

Is there any way to 'order by' by this 'ordering' key .

The dictionary values(vip, vip+,regular) corresponds with a column in my companies list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though your ordering dictionary is back-to-front with respect to the way you need to use it, which is to look up based on a text key and give a numeric ordering. I would recommend 'inverting' your ordering dictionary first, then you can sort the companies for the cost of a dictionary lookup per entry, plus the cost of the LINQ sorting algorithm.

```
var swappedOrdering = ordering.ToDictionary(kvp => k.Value, kvp => k.Key);
var orderedCompanies = companies.OrderBy(c => ordering[c.CompanyCategory]);
```

Keep in mind though that your ordering dictionary is memory, not in the database, so in order to use this approach you would need to spool all the records back into memory. If you want the database to do the hard work, you'll have to put this ordering information into the database.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Jon G said, you can also do it with a join. Something like this should do the trick:

```
var companyQuery = from c in companies
                   join kvp in ordering on c.CompanyCategory equals kvp.Value
                   orderby kvp.Key
                   select c;
```

Comment: no i can not. it throws an exception. Linq to sql can not join db queries to local list

Comment: That's true. I was assuming that you had already loaded the company list into memory previously. I don't think you'll be able to do what you're trying to do unless you 1) Load the companies into memory first, or 2) Put the "ordering" dictionary in its own database table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom OrderBy statement like:

```
public List<Company> OrderCompanies()
{
    Dictionary<int, string> ordering = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    ordering.Add(1, "VIP");
    ordering.Add(2, "VIP+");
    ordering.Add(3, "Regular");

    // This could be the database source
    List<Company> companies = new List<Company>();
    companies.Add(new Company() { CompanyCategory = "VIP" });
    companies.Add(new Company() { CompanyCategory = "VIP+" });

    return companies
        .OrderBy(company => ordering.First(pair => pair.Value == company.CompanyCategory).Key)
        .ToList();
}
```